# Airtable - How to change Api link Onclick JS?

Tags: javascript, api, airtable

I have this JS script, who call an Airtable API

```
var type = "Coupons"
var api_key = "?api_key=123456"
var maxRecords = "&maxRecords=10"
var filterByFormula = "&filterByFormula=%7Bvip_ou_50%7D%3D%2250%222"
var offset = "";
var url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/app123456/" + type + api_key + maxRecords + "&offset=" + offset + "&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=coupons_id";

async function catchJson() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();....
```

as you see next, I created a function to change the value of the offset

```
var next_page = function () {
    console.log(offset);
    offset = data.offset;
    console.log(offset);
}
page_suivante.onclick = next_page;
```

so I want to create a next page bouton Onclick that change the offset value

How can I do that !

Thanks for your help !

This is my result page for now : https://web.pinkmarket.co

Edit : this is my full JS with correction

```js
var type = "Coupons"
var api_key = "?api_key=1234"
var maxRecords = "&maxRecords=10"
var filterByFormula = "&filterByFormula=%7Bvip_ou_50%7D%3D%2250%222"
var offset = "&offset"

var url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/app1234/" + type + api_key + offset + "&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=coupons_id";

const app = document.getElementById('root')

const card = document.createElement('div');
card.setAttribute('class', 'rightcontainer w-container')

app.appendChild(card)

async function catchJson() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();

    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 400) {
        data.records.forEach(records => {

            const records_length = document.getElementById('number')
            records_length.innerHTML = 'Liste de coupons <br> <a href="" class="button-2 left-aligned w-button"><span class="text-span-2">Ouvrir la Map</span></a>'

            const property_card = document.createElement('a')
            property_card.setAttribute('class', 'property-card left w-inline-block w-clearfix')
            property_card.style.background = "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(29%, hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0)), color-stop(68%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5))), url('" + records.fields.image_url + "');";
            property_card.style.background = "linear - gradient(180deg, hsla(0, 0 %, 100 %, 0) 29 %, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 68 %), url('" + records.fields.image_url + "');"

            const image_quantity_div = document.createElement('div')
            image_quantity_div.setAttribute('class', 'image-quantity-div')

            const price_text = document.createElement('h1')
            price_text.setAttribute('class', 'price-text')
            price_text.innerText = records.fields.titre

            const div_lower_info = document.createElement('div')
            div_lower_info.setAttribute('class', 'div-lower-info w-clearfix')

            const info_text = document.createElement('div')
            info_text.setAttribute('class', 'info-text')
            info_text.innerText = records.fields.compagny_name + ' - ' + records.fields.description_sub.substring(0, 100) + '...'

            const view_button = document.createElement('div')
            view_button.setAttribute('class', 'view-button')
            view_button.textContent = 'Plus'

            root.appendChild(card);

            card.appendChild(property_card);

            property_card.appendChild(image_quantity_div);

            property_card.appendChild(price_text);

            div_lower_info.appendChild(info_text);
            div_lower_info.appendChild(view_button);

            property_card.appendChild(div_lower_info);

        })

        const offset_page = document.createElement('a');
        offset_page.setAttribute('class', 'button-2 left-aligned w-button')
        offset_page.setAttribute('id', 'next')
        offset_page.setAttribute('href', data.offset)
        offset_page.innerHTML = "Page Suivante"

        card.appendChild(offset_page);
        });
    }
    else {
        const errorMessage = document.createElement('a')
        errorMessage.textContent = `Bah, ça ne marche pas !`
        app.appendChild(errorMessage)
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    catchJson()
});
```

```html
<div class="premium-properties-div" id="root">
            </div>
```

Comment: whats ```page_suivante```

Comment: @seriously that mean next_page

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right you want to run the `next_page()` function on button click. If so this code does that:

**EDIT:** As discussed in the comments the below code will update your `offset` variable without restarting.

````js
var type = "Coupons"
var api_key = "?api_key=123456"
var maxRecords = "&maxRecords=10"
var filterByFormula = "&filterByFormula=%7Bvip_ou_50%7D%3D%2250%222"
//I assume you set the ofset to "" because as discussed in the comments you get the offset value after calling the api the first time
var offset = "";
var url = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/app123456/" + type + api_key + maxRecords + "&offset=" + offset + "&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=coupons_id";

var dynamicOffset = []

//your finalData
var finalData = []

//on click of button the api starts running.
document.getElementById("nextPageBtn").addEventListener('click', function() {
  getNewOffset()
});

function getNewOffset() {
  async function catchJson() {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();

    //as disscussed in the comments ```data``` is the offset value you get back so now insert the offset value to the URL and run it again and again untill no ofset value is returned

    //so first check if data is not empty then if not lets push every new offset data returned to an array called ```dynamic Offset``` but also empty the array before pushing then call the second fetch method.
    if (data != "" && data != null) {
      dynamicOffset = []
      dynamicOffset.push(data)
      secondFetch()
    } else {
      console.log('not more new offset')
      //Log your final data
      console.log(finalData)
    }
  }
}

function secondFetch() {
  //insert the new Offset Value
  const modifiedURL = "https://api.airtable.com/v0/app123456/" + type + api_key + maxRecords + "&offset=" + dynamicOffset[0] + "&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=coupons_id";

  //call fetch
  async function catchJson() {
    const response = await fetch(modifiedURL);
    const data = await response.json();

    //we didn't discuss how you want your final data to be saved but assuming your data are strings lets push them all to ```finalDataArray``` but you can save them in your desierd way. Note we are not clearing array here becuase we are appending not writing.

    //just a precaution statment
    if (data != "" && data != null) {
      finalData.push(data)
      //lets setTimeout of 1 second to avoid memory overload
      setTimeout(() => {
        //call getNewOffset() again
        getNewOffset()
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
}
````

```html
<button id="nextPageBtn">Next Page</button>
```

Comment: Exactly what i need

Comment: But I don't see how to do it I heard that, it's require Ajax because can't change var without refreshing page

Comment: With the offset value , we can create a pagination


reference : [How to paginate records in Airtable when using the API](https://chinarajames.com/how-to-paginate-records-in-airtable-when-using-the-api/)

Comment: what is your main goal is it to change the offset value dynamically or do you need to send data to/from client to server-side?

Comment: so the thing is ...

when you call Airtable API you get only 100 records per call

but i have more than 1000 records

so to get the next 100 record i need to call a offset value 

this is the offset value exemple : "offset":"itrIdPemLoezgO5kN/recqKwI4DZqzuKS5Y"

so to call the next 100 recoard i have to add :` offset=trIdPemLoezgO5kN/recqKwI4DZqzuKS5Y` at the end of my api url call

Comment: but each call have different offset value and what I want is to change the offset value by the new one with the Onclick Function !

Comment: oh got it so you dont need ajax because you are not communicating with your back end. I will add code to show you how to update a variable without refresing.

Comment: check now and comment if you have any questions.

Comment: so if i understand i dont have to update my code just add your code and its should work !!!

Comment: If so I'm testing the code thanks very much for your help, ill come back on that !

Comment: i have an error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')`

Comment: This is my full JS script now : https://jsfiddle.net/KazeroG/kpnec1ht/3/

Comment: that is because your fetch system is not right remember we are pushing ``data.offset``` to our offset array then we are applying offset array to url but right now you are constructing the url and calling fetch before data.offset is pushed to offset array. Did you get the problem?

Comment: To be honest, I'm lost from there ! If you can maybe correct my code ?

Comment: ok I will try to. check back in like an hour I will fix and update the code above

Comment: in your earlier comment you said ```"offset":"itrIdPemLoezgO5kN/recqKwI4DZqzuKS5Y"``` as an example. where do you get those offset values from?

Comment: From my API URL data at the end of the records : 

https://api.airtable.com/v0/appk3OIY3chtMfqK3/Coupons?api_key=keyNDM4WhNKOapUN7&offset&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=coupons_id

CTRL+F : offset

Comment: any update on that question ?

Comment: @KazeroG hey sorry had a busy couple of weeks. It's really easy to solve your problem there is only one thing I couldn't get. Remember I asked you where you are getting those offset values from, when you make a different call at your api after 100 calls have been made you want to change the offset value and click on the button to recall API right? If so do you like want to enter down the new offset value in an input box then call the API does that work for you? So that it will be as easy as entering offset then pressing button then getting data.

Comment: don't worry about that, I understand we all have something to do outside internet :) and I want to thank you for your help tho !

To reply to your message : not really don't want to add input and I can't, why ? Because I want my clients to go to the next page whiteout doing that !

Comment: This is another explanation, sorry if I'm not clear :


so i call an API with this URL : `https://api.airtable.com/v0/appk3OIY3chtMfqK3/Coupons?api_key=keyNDM4WhNKOapUN7`



then i get data like that : [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cGwQVWEVyDVhuNaLEFLtGf3aYldjUlMd/preview)

Comment: then at the end i have an offset value : [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RJtcK62sJ9NHf1hbQEuLTk34XWwwkMhK/preview)

then i have to parse the offset value in the api URL :
`https://api.airtable.com/v0/appk3OIY3chtMfqK3/Coupons?api_key=keyNDM4WhNKOapUN7` add at the end `&offset=itrihrLv4sHkXAloW/rec5d6vGgwQnCO2df` to get the next page

Comment: Then I do it in loop for each new offset value i got i add new page

Comment: I cant look at the images because it says google drive access denied.

Comment: so just to confirm first call api with ```https://api.airtable.com/v0/appk3OIY3chtMfqK3/Coupons?api_key=keyNDM4WhNKOapUN7``` then (couldn't see the data but assuming its an offset value get that offset value) then add it to the end of the API URL then call the API again. and then loop until no offset value is returned. Is that correct?

Comment: somehow yes it's correct
&
sorry about the img...

Comment: hi @KazeroG check the updated code and read the comments I added all over and feel free to comments back with more questions or if I missed something